# Connect to Azure CosmosDB

Tags: mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to connect to CosmosDB, I use connection string from Quick Start,
it is working fine on my localhost but once I deploy I get

```
{
name: "MongoError",
message: "Database account is not found"
}

var express = require('express'),
mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoUri = "mongodb://dbaccount:pass@dbhost:port/dbNAME?ssl=true';
options = {
"useMongoClient":true,
"promiseLibrary": global.Promise,
"ssl": true
}
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var db = mongoose.connect(mongoUri,options)
```

I've checked connection string. I can connect on my localhost also I can connect to db using Robo 3T.

Comment: When you set up Cosmos DB, did you choose the MongoDB API or the DocumentDB API? Needs to be MongoDB API. Also, it would be helpful if you edited your question and shared your connection string (PLEASE OBSCURE/CHANGE the real database name or access key). In your example, you just have `dbaccount` and `dbhost`  - not enough to tell if there's a connection string format issue.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Add the IP from your web app on Azure to the IP Access Control List on you Firewall on your DB.

[image]

I had exactly the same issue, I could connect locally and with Robo 3T, but once I deployed the app on Azure I received this error:

```
MongoError: Database account is not found
at Function.MongoError.create (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:497:72
at authenticateStragglers (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:443:16)
at Connection.messageHandler (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:477:5)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:331:22)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:594:20)
```

So chances are high, that something with the firewall settings on Azure is wrong.

For me, I disabled my the IP Access Control on the db on Azure and the error disappeared and everything worked as expected. I turned IP Access Control back on and added the IP from the web app, to allow access. That should do the trick.
I think you can access from your localhost because your local IP is already added as default for development purposes.

See this Microsoft Doc for further information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/firewall-support

Comment: This solved my issue except that I was receiving "MongoError: authentication fail" in the event someone stumbles across this answer with my same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. In your Azure Cosmos DB you just have to enable this:

[image]

This will allow other Azure resources (such a Web App) to access your database.